# How to fix $_GET Error?

Tags: php, get

I am passing form data from one page to the other.

Below is the code of the form action, verify.php:

```
<?php  

header("Location: http://domain.com/rd/r.php?&email=<?php echo $_GET['email']; ?>"); 

?>
```

However, i keep getting the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in /home/thanksfo/public_html/LP/x/verify.php on line 3
```

Any idea how to fix it? It says unexpected whitespace or t_encapsed. don't really know what is wrong ...

Comment: Make sure that `$_GET['email']` is actually defined; and `?&email=...` can be simply `?email=...`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct syntax for double quoted strings is:

```
header("Location: http://domain.com/rd/r.php?&email=$_GET[email]");
```

You can't have `<?php` code within a string, in particular the closing `?>` broke the syntax for you.

- The array syntax sans quotes is only valid in this context, not in plain PHP code.
- And as @Aarolama Bluenk pointed out, [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) is advisable:

  `$formatted = urlencode($_GET['email']);`
  `header("Location: http://domain.com/rd/r.php?&email=$formatted");`

It is also wise to [sanitize](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.sanitization.php) the e-mail address if not yet done so.

Comment: I would probably `urlencode` that email.

Comment: `$_GET[email]` will raise a notice, unlike when used inside the double quoted string.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by others, using `<?php ?>` syntax inside strings won't work. On top of that, you should also make sure that resulting URL is valid:

```
header("Location: http://domain.com/rd/r.php?" . http_build_query(array(
    'email' => $_GET['email'],
)));
```

*I've also replaced the `"?&"` part of the URL with simply `"?"`*

See also: [`http_build_query()`](http://www.php.net/http_build_query)

Optionally, you could [filter](http://www.php.net/filter) the email address:

```
$email = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'email', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
```

Using this, `$email` can be:

- `null` - the value is not passed
- `false` - it's not a valid email
- The email address as a string

Answer (score 1):

or try, i think also work

```
<?php  

header("Location: http://domain.com/rd/r.php?&email=".$_GET['email']); 

?>
```